# HTTPS image url not loading in FBSDKShareDialog with FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject

Tags: ios, facebook, https, self-signed, fbsdk

I am trying post a image url to facebook with FBSDKShareDialog. The image url has https and a self-signed certificate is used. But the https image url does not render before and after posting to facebook. Below is the code I use to share on facebook:

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [FBSDKSharePhoto photoWithImageURL:imageURL userGenerated:NO];
    // Create an object
    NSDictionary *properties = @{
                                 @"og:type": @"fit:class",
                                 @"og:title": sliceClass.className,
                                 @"og:description": desc,
                                 @"og:url": myURL,
                                 @"og:image": @[photo]
                                 };
    FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];

    // Create an action
    FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
    action.actionType = @"fit:book";
    [action setObject:object forKey:@"fit:class"];

    // Create the content
    FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
    content.action = action;
    content.previewPropertyName = @"fit:class";

    [[FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:nil] share];


    FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
    shareDialog.fromViewController = vc;
    shareDialog.shareContent = content;
    [shareDialog setShareContent:content];
    [shareDialog setFromViewController:vc];
    [shareDialog show];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use a self signed certificate

Comment: what if there is no other option?

Comment: Then don't use https.

Comment: in this scenario, I must use HTTPS with a self-signed certificate.

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to share?

Comment: an image url. it starts with https and it has a self-signed certificate